# Unlock all Azure file share locks

Tags: azure, network-share

I have an Azure file share (SMB) with files. When I try to rename/delete a file I get an "The specified resource may be in use by an SMB client" error. There are multiple servers that connect to this SMB share and I have no way of telling which server or which process has the lock. How can I unlock this file or how can I release all file locks currently in use?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this problem, however I do not think this is the 'normal' way to do so:

- edit the 'Firewalls and virtual networks' section of the storage account and set it to 'Selected Networks'
- do not assign any IP addresses/ranges or remove existing ones
- wait for 30 minutes
- set the 'Firewalls and virtual networks' section of the storage account and set it to the original setting or 'All Networks'
- The connection from the external server is disconnected and the lock is gone

Comment: Before I try this just wanted to understand what are the consequence of switching network from ALL to selected.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact issue recently. You can unlock the file using the [Close-AzStorageFileHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/close-azstoragefilehandle?view=azps-11.2.0) command from the azure cli. After unlocking it you should be able to delete it.

You connect to the azure cli, setup your context for the storage account and then enter the path to the file you want to unlock.
The entire process would be these 4 commands

```
connect-azaccount
Set-AzContext -Subscription "<subscription id>"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<storage account name>" -StorageAccountKey "<storage account key found in the storage account key section>"
Close-AzStorageFileHandle -Context $context -ShareName "<share name>" -Path '<path>' -CloseAll
```